# Are Drivers Available for Ubuntu Kodak 7.1 Hero Printer?

Tags: printing, kodak

This looks like a nice printer I came across at a local store. Its the "Kodak 7.1 Hero". I cannot seem to find if this will work on Ubuntu and if drivers are easily obtainable? The official site only says "windows & mac", but I have seen a YouTube video showing the google cloud printing feature working in Ubuntu. The video was in German so I couldnt make sense of it. Ive also check the open printers website and no info there.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/) has an interesting project which could be just your saviour...

> cups filters and ppd files, and sane backend, for the kodak ESP and
>   Hero all in one printers on linux. Likely to work on all ESP and Hero
>   printers

There is a report here for the [v9.1 version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/forums/forum/1107084/topic/4792078) of your printer.

The dev's are asking for testers and to report issues - so hopefully they can help if you run into issues.

**to install**

Download the deb package and install via the syntax

```
sudo dpkg -i [deb-package-name].deb
```

Comment: Thank you so much Fossfreedom (once again)! I voted for you! Good Luck!

Comment: ... thanks! To be honest - if you havent bought the printer already... personally I would stick with HP or Epson printers.  They have much better linux support from the manufacturers themselves.

Comment: I do have to agree with you unless Kodak were to start coming out with drivers all of a sudden. Then we would be talking about them a lot more I think. At work we have only HP and they work well with all the Ubuntu computers we have. At home Im stuck with a freebie Canon i2600 and it works fine in 11.10 (miraculously as it was a pain with 10.10).